# Timeout Chaining Method

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout

So I have a question regarding chaining timeouts. I have 2 methods here which I am deciding what to use from. Method 1 is definitely a lot cleaner, however I am not sure if it is less accurate or slower in terms of performance than the other?

**Method 1:**

```
setTimeout(() => {

}, 1 * 60000);

setTimeout(() => {

}, 2 * 60000);

setTimeout(() => {

}, 3 * 60000);
```

**Method 2:**

```
setTimeout(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {

        }, 1 * 60000);
    }, 1 * 60000);
}, 1 * 60000);
```

Comment: completely out of curiosity, where will you apply this?

Comment: It will be used for a countdown, with different logic inside each setTimeout (so setIntervals can't be used).

Comment: Method 2 is recomended... Let me run some tests and see

Comment: In terms of performance those two are pretty identical

Comment: @hindmost  I kind of doubt.. In method 1, aren't all timeouts gonna be called at once (same time)? Compared to method 2?

Comment: @Nelson Owalo No. 1st timeout - at `1 * 60000`, 2nd - `2 * 60000`, and 3rd - `3 * 60000`. Exactly as Method 2, apart from browser-specific delays.

Comment: Avoid method 1,.  Timeout's use handles, and you can assume there a precious resource.

Comment: you are right...

Answer (score 0):

My tests show that method 2 is faster. I repeated the test about 10 times. I used the Chrome Performance Dev Tool.

[image]
[image]

I've used this code:

```js
function runFirst() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(1);
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(2);
  }, 2 * 1000);
}

function runSecond() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(3);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(4);
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
}
```

However, these difference are really minimal. I'd recommend using the code that is better readable (method 1).

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 is faster. Here is the code I tested: [Benchmark](http://jsben.ch/p2xuU)

```
// function1
function func1() {
  setTimeout(() => { }, 1 * 60000);          
  setTimeout(() => { }, 2 * 60000);  
  setTimeout(() => { }, 3 * 60000);
  return 'done'
}

func1()

// function2
function func2() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setTimeout(() => { }, 1 * 60000);
    }, 1 * 60000);
  }, 1 * 60000);
  return 'done';
}

func2()
```

[Here](http://jsben.ch/p2xuU) are the [results](http://jsben.ch/p2xuU)